# Probabilistic Conditioning. Please help me finish the solution to the problem.

Tags: probability, bayes-theorem

I have to solve the following problem:

The real random variables $X$ and $Y$ are independent and have a uniform distribution $U([0,1])$. Find

$$\mathbb{E}\left( \frac{3 X-Y+1}{\sqrt{X+Y+1}} |  \quad e^{X+Y}-20 \log(X+Y) \right)$$

Answer: $\sqrt{X+Y+1}$.

My solution: In the condition there is the function $f(y)=e^y-20 \log(y)$. Its derivative is as follows: $f'(y)=e^y-\frac{20}{y}$. Let us note that for $y\in (0,2]$ this derivative is negative, i.e. $f$ is strictly decreasing in $(0,2]$ and $0 < X+Y < 2$ a.s. Hence follows that
$$\sigma\left( e^{X+Y}-20 \log(X+Y) \right)=\sigma(X+Y),$$
so we have
$$\mathbb{E}\left( \frac{3 X-Y+1}{\sqrt{X+Y+1}} |  \quad e^{X+Y}-20 \log(X+Y) \right)=\mathbb{E}\left( \frac{3 X-Y+1}{\sqrt{X+Y+1}} |  X+Y \right)$$
Hence
$$\mathbb{E}\left( \frac{3 X-Y+1}{\sqrt{X+Y+1}} |  X+Y \right)=\mathbb{E}\left( \frac{2 X-2Y+X+Y+1}{\sqrt{X+Y+1}} |  X+Y \right)=$$
$$=\mathbb{E}\left( \frac{X+Y+1}{\sqrt{X+Y+1}} |  X+Y \right)+2 \mathbb{E}\left( \frac{X-Y}{\sqrt{X+Y+1}} |  X+Y \right)=$$
$$=\sqrt{X+Y+1}+\frac{2}{\sqrt{X+Y+1}}\mathbb{E}(X-Y|X+Y).$$

Now, I am not far from a complete solution, but I don't know how to prove that $\mathbb{E}(X-Y|X+Y)=0$. In the case of normality $N(0,1)$, it wouldn't be a problem because $$\mathrm{cov}(X+Y,X-Y)=E((X+Y)(X-Y))-E(X+Y)E(X-Y)=$$
$$E((X+Y)(X-Y))=E(X^2-Y^2)=1-1=0,$$
and for the normal distribution zero correlation implies indepedence hence we would have $\mathbb{E}(X-Y|X+Y)=\mathbb{E}(X-Y)=0$.

But how is it for the case of uniformity????

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So basically the thing you want to prove is that:

$$\mathbb{E}(X-Y|X+Y)=0$$, where $X, Y$ are independent uniformly distributed random variables.

This is easy to see, since $\mathbb{E}(X|X+Y)=\mathbb{E}(Y|X+Y)$ due to the symmetry of the problem (i.e. just relabel $X$ and $Y$)! Now just use linearity of conditional expectation to finish the proof.

In particular, the only thing this proof needs is that $X$ and $Y$ are i.i.d. random variables in $\mathcal{L}^1$.